# Why when I use github actions CI for a gradle project I face "./gradlew: Permission denied" error?

Tags: gradle, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a very simple gradle project and when I setup GitHub Actions CI I face this error:

```
Run ./gradlew clean dependencies
  ./gradlew clean dependencies
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java/8.0.222/x64
    JAVA_HOME_8.0.222_x64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java/8.0.222/x64
/home/runner/work/_temp/8f29e484-fbb4-4e29-a02a-679519aec24c.sh: line 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied
##[error]Process completed with exit code 126.
```

Answer (score 43):

I found the answer!

I just had to change the gradlew file permission on the git repository to make it executable using this command:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
git commit -m "Make gradlew executable"
```

it was simple but killed my time!

Answer (score 25):

To solve this issue, you might need to add `chmod` action before `gradle` one. Like this one:

```
- name: Change wrapper permissions
  run: chmod +x ./gradlew
```

So overall workflow file may look like this:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Change wrapper permissions
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

Comment: now i am stuck here ./gradlew: line 1: version: command not found
./gradlew: line 2: oid: command not found
size: '8070': No such file

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention another potential issue that happened to me even though the above changes were made.

I made the mistake of:

```
./gradle
```

when it was supposed to be

```
./gradlew
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added permission and also updated to run with JDK 11,it's better

```
 steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
         java-version: 11
         
      - name: Grant execute permission to Gradle wrapper
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
```

Comment: Different approaches, same result 