# cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory Github actions

Tags: android, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using workflow on GithubActions but getting the following error:

```
chmod: cannot access './gradlew': No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Following is my workflow.yml file

```
name: Android CI

on:
 push:
branches: [ develop ]
 pull_request:
branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build:

  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Set up JDK 1.8
  uses: actions/setup-java@v1
  with:
    java-version: 1.8
- name: Change wrapper permissions
  run: chmod +x ./gradlew
- name: Build with Gradle
  run: ./gradlew build
```

I tried you change chmod command in a different way but non of execution succeed, but same workflow on my other project is working file i don't know whats the issue, Any help highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and I found someone change it to

- name: gradlew
  run: gradle
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fRpC.png)
  with removing "./" and "w"

and worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't initialise wrapper.

You can try clone your repository from scratch and the exetuce `./gradlew build` command. If it's failed. Try use the

```
gradle wrapper
```

This command init your wrapper and you can see which files was generated and required for `./gradlew`

Finally, You have two options:

- Run `gradle wrapper` locally and push required files

or

- Add extra step to *init wrapper* during the workflow

  ```
  ...

  jobs:
    build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Set up JDK 1.8
  uses: actions/setup-java@v1
  with:
    java-version: 1.8
  - name: Change wrapper permissions
    run: chmod +x ./gradlew

  - name: Init gradle wrapper
    run: gradle wrapper

  - name: Change wrapper permissions
    run: chmod +x ./gradlew

  - name: Build with Gradle wrapper
    run: ./gradlew build
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to change chmod command in a different way

That wouldn't change the fact the file itself (`gradlew`) seems to be missing.
I would check if it is anywhere (`run: find / -type f -name "gradlew"`), considering the [`actions/setup-java`](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) is supposed to include Gradle.

That would be just for testing, as a first step:

```yaml
- name: Look for gradlew
  run: find / -type f -name "gradlew"
- name: Change wrapper permissions
...
```

If it is in the `$PATH`, this [issue suggests](https://github.com/actions/setup-java/issues/89#issuecomment-773157721):

> I changed
> "`./gradle build`" to "`gradle build`" in Build with Gradle step.
>
> That solved the issue. (see [`gradle-publish.yml`](https://github.com/sumitnekar/service-cars/blob/setup-github-actions/.github/workflows/gradle-publish.yml))

Comment: where to put this run: find / -type f -name "gradlew" ??

Comment: @JhamanDas I have edited the answer to illustrate that approach.

Comment: getting premission denied in all the process https://ibb.co/3Cnqzyk

Comment: @JhamanDas That is expected, since some files/folders are not reachable by a non-root user. Try `find / -type f -name "gradlew" 2>/dev/null`, in order to focus on what it can find, as opposed to all those errors.

Comment: These commands are taking too much time in execution

Comment: this is failed with this error. https://ibb.co/16yYJG0

Comment: @JhamanDas The final exit status (error 1) is expected. But at least you see where `gradlew` is. Try a `run echo $PATH` and `run which gradlew`, to see if one of those gradlew found is in your PATH.

Comment: and where to put path once i found?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238830/discussion-between-vonc-and-jhaman-das).

Answer (score 0):

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58282862/14534473) helped me solve the same problem. You just have to change the gradlew file permission using this code: Run this on the terminal

```
git update-index --chmod=+x gradlew
git commit -m "Make gradlew executable"
```

I also removed `chmod +x` from my workflow.yml file after changing the gradlew file permissions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `./gradlew`, try using `gradle`. This worked for me.